# The button does not respond when dynamically loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

I wrote a script to upload files to the server. If the input and the  tag are part of the document permanently, there is no problem - everything works, throws in. The problem arises when I load the form to be uploaded dynamically using the .html () function

Then upload stops working. As you can see, I do it in the way $ (document) .on ("click", "element"), but it does not give much.

I forgot something? Did I miss something?

```js
$(".user-av").on("click", function(e) {

  $(".dialog-global").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".dialog-head").html("<p>Update avatar</p>");
  $(".dialog-content").html('<input type="file" class="set-av" /><a href="#" class="upload-av-btn orange-btn">Upload</a>');

  e.stopPropagation();

});

$(document).on("click", ".upload-av-btn", function(e) {

  var files = $(".set-av").prop("files")[0];
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", files);

  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form,
    type: "post",
  }).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });

  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".user-av").on("click", function(e) {

  $(".dialog-global").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".dialog-head").html("<p>Update avatar</p>");
  $(".dialog-content").html('<input type="file" class="set-av" /><a href="#" class="upload-av-btn orange-btn">Upload</a>');

  e.stopPropagation();

});

$(document).on("click", ".dialog-content .upload-av-btn", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var files = $(".set-av").prop("files")[0];
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", files);

  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form,
    type: "post",
  }).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });

});

});
```

Comment: I tried this before, unfortunately it does not work. I do not know if it's about downloading data from FormData here?